# Can Lombok be used with JAXB and @XmlType propOrder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, getter-setter, lombok

I cannot get @XmlType with propOrder working with Lombok:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "street",
        "postalCode",
        "city",
        "country"})
public class Alternative extends BaseAddress {

    @XmlElement
    private String street;

    @XmlElement
    private String city;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "postalCode",
        "country"})
public abstract class BaseAddress implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    private String postalCode;

    @XmlElement
    private String country;
```

I get errors on fields postalCode and country if I use lombok:

**Field 'postalCode' does not exist**

**Field 'country' does not exist**

Do you guys know why and if lombok supports the JAXB structure?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Lombok because even with getters & setters (w/o lombok annotations) you would run into the same issue. You cannot specify parent class properties in the child class' `propOrder` because with inheritance, properties from parent class are always set first. So there are two approaches. You either follow the order of parent props and then child props:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"street", "city"})
public class Alternative extends BaseAddress {
..
@XmlType(propOrder = {"postalCode", "country"})
public abstract class BaseAddress {
```

Or you annotate base class with `@XmlTransient`

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"postalCode", "country", "street", "city"})
public class Alternative extends BaseAddress {
..
@XmlTransient
public abstract class BaseAddress {
```

Taken from `@XmlTransient` doc:

> When placed on a class, it indicates that the class shouldn't be mapped
> to XML by itself. Properties on such class will be mapped to XML along
> with its derived classes, as if the class is inlined.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "street",
        "postalCode",
        "city",
        "country"})
public class Alternative extends BaseAddress {

    @XmlElement
    private String street;

    @XmlElement
    private String city;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlTransient
public abstract class BaseAddress implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    private String postalCode;

    @XmlElement
    private String country;
```

Adding **@XmlTransient** and **@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)** to both classes did the job.

**@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) means none of the fields is mapped to XML unless they have some JAXB annotations.**